# Angular KendoUI Grid Conditional Password Field

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid

I've got a KendoUI Grid with the edit functionality that I use to handle configuration parameters, some of which are encrypted passwords. [The editor property](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ColumnComponent/#toc-editor) of the grid doesn't allow for password type fields, and I can't make all edit fields on that column password type because not all of them are, so the object has a property `encrypted`, which I want to use in a custom ng-template to change the input type.

How can I make it so the edit field becomes `type="password"` only when the `encrypted` property is `true`?

```
<ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-column="column" let-formGroup="formGroup" let-isNew="isNew">
    <input class="k-input" #valueInput [formControl]="formGroup.get(column.field)" />
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is property binding.

```
 <input class="k-input" [type]="encrypted ? 'password' : 'text'" #valueInput [formControl]="formGroup.get(column.field)" />
```

Comment: encrypted doens't seem to be within the scope of the input being generated, or at least not plainly available like your example.

Comment: I must have misunderstood. Where is your object with the ```encrypted``` property being referenced then?